# iPhone started hanging after activating developement

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, freeze

I know this is weird question but I am not getting why this is happening.

When I run app for testing on my colleague iPhone he starting complaining that his iPhone hangs for 2-3 seconds sometimes.

At first, Colleague iPhone was not set for development. I activated the development.

**Note:**

Hanging process starts anytime. Not necessary when he open that app.

Also his iPhone is registered with another apple accounts also (means different account provision files)

Have iOS 6.1.3 on colleague iPhone.

**The problem is colleague iPhone started hanging after I activated the developer account.**

Someone have any idea why this is happening?

This is something wrong, but this is happening.

Comment: Try testing it on another device. Does it work well on the simulator ?

Comment: @giorashc : yes, its works perfectly on my iPhone and simulator. Also its not app problem. His iPhone started hanging after i activated the developer account.

Comment: check the version of of iOS in his phone! May be you have used some framework that are not perfectly work on it or it may be low memory issue!

Comment: @iphonemaclover : its not with app... its like after activating development on his iPhone, it starts hanging. he have latest iOS.

Comment: Does he have ios 7 ? I heard there were problems with the beta version

Comment: @giorashc : no, he have iOS 6.1.3

Comment: not sure due to apple development the phone will hang.Do one thing just remove that app from iPhone.Restart the iPhone.Make a try.....:)

Comment: @iPhoneDev : he restarted many times, but still problem persisting.